# What added value would an internal technical pentest have for a small barebones office with basic protections?

Tags: penetration-test

Assuming that a small office where basic security hygiene is already applied wants to improve their security posture, would such an office benefit from a **technical internal pentest** ?

Such an office's network would be rather simple : a Domain Controller, a file server, and a few end-user workstations, all of which are regularly patched, with the external perimeter protected by a regularly patched firewall. The Domain policies notably include a strong password policy and authentication rate limiting.

No web servers are deployed, the end-users simply use desktop software to create encrypted connections towards simple database files stored on the file server.

In such a context, what value would an internal technical pentest yield ?

(phishing simulations & generic awareness are out of scope for this question ; assuming that those are already done on a regular basis, but out of scope anyways).
All I can see would be network sniffing to intercept data such as NTLM hashes, that would be hard to crack anyways ; am I missing something, even with such a small attack surface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is **Assurance**. You need to know whether:

- what you have intended for your controls is working as intended
- that you have not missed anything
- there are not other considerations that you need to take into account

Security is never "fire and forget". It always shifts. And size doesn't matter. I do many (a hundred a year?) assessments like this for organisations of different sizes and I *always* uncover surprises. Mostly misconfigurations, shadow IT, or configurations made by people who didn't fully understand the consequences.

An assessment process will **assure** you that you know what you need to know and that you don't have "unknown unknowns" that could present an unacceptable risk to you.

Comment: for the record, in this theoretical case, internal controls (such as : verifying patching levels on workstations and servers, verifying Domain Controller policies), would be performed once in a while ; but your approach with the angle of Assurance makes total sense ; thanks for the reply

Comment: Shadow IT is a huge one, and usually arises when the intended processes are too slow or complicated. Definitely an underrated risk